# java - lotto read from text file

Tags: java, math, random, console, compare

My console is supposed to read sets of numbers from a text file. The numbers in the file must be compared to 7 'lucky numbers'. The program must find out how many people had 3 matches, 4 matches, 5 matches, 6 matches and 7 matches with the 'lucky numbers', and the results must be printed at the end.

**I dont know how to do the comparing between the numbers in the file and generating the 'lucky numbers'.**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;

public class Lotto {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner lottoFile = new Scanner(new File("c:\\Exercises\\New Folder\\Lotto.txt"));
        ArrayList<Double> lotto = new ArrayList<Double>();

        while(lottoFile.hasNextLine()){
            String line = lottoFile.nextLine();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            while(scanner.hasNextDouble()){
                lotto.add(scanner.nextDouble());
            }
            scanner.close();
        }

        lottoFile.close();

        System.out.println(lotto);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you consider looking at the Math class? specifically the `random` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Step 1. Put the lucky numbers in a HashSet, this will make it easy to check if some number is a lucky number.

Step 2. For every person in the input, count how many of their numbers are in the lucky numbers set using [HashSet.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-).